# How to only minfy concatenated js in Prepros

Tags: javascript, prepros

Is there a way to generally NOT minify js files but DO minify a single concatenated version?

Basically here's the issue:
Large project with 100's of files.
During development we don't serve up minified js files as they don't add any benefit and just slow us down having to 'compile' a file every time you make a change. 
However in production we concatenate the core framework files into a single minified and source mapped file.

Currently we do this using a 'Bundle' via WebEssentials in VisualStudio, the bundle is just an xml file listing the files to concat with attributes saying whether we want it minified and whether we want a source map generated. We also do the same thing with css files. Both are output into a 'release' folder.

Answer (score 1):

in the current version, you can do the following

```
prepros ui >> right-click on project name >> Project Filters
```

**add *.js to exclude all js files**, if you want to minifiy a single file and exclude others, i think you need play with filters specified.